# How to create a line graph that connects points without data in between - R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
abc <- tibble(month = c(1, 3, 12),
              amount = c(100, 20, 300))

abc %>% 
    mutate(month = as.factor(month)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = month, y = amount, group = 1)) +
    geom_line()
```

I would like to create a line graph on the x-axis showing 1 to 12 as in showing every month and the y-axis is the amount spent. So for example, February will be zero and March will be 20.

Thank you.

Comment: "So for example, February will be zero" - Are you truly wanting to represent the missing values as zero? Or are they actually NA? Assigning the months missing from your example dataset with a zero value denotes that they exist. It appears NA is more appropriate.

Comment: I want to represent as zero so when I draw the line so that it is saying I didn’t  spend any money in February.  I have other year in the table that has a value in Feb.

Comment: One further consideration to add in addition to the answer below, you may want to consider using a bar chart rather than a line chart for your data. That's because technically you have discrete data points and a line plot implies data "between" points.

Comment: A bar chart would be better but I have another bar chart in my project so I figured I would play around with the line chart as part of my education. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mention that you have data for more than one year is rather important so I added a column year in the table and work with it in a more general way.

```r
# modified data including the year
abc <- tibble(month= c(1, 3, 12, 2),
              year = c(rep(2021, 3), 2022),
              amount = c(100, 20, 300, 10))

# all year x month combinations with 0 amount
abc.full <- expand.grid(month = seq_len(12),
                        year = unique(abc$year),
                        amount = 0)

# fill in amount where available
abc.full$amount[match(paste(abc$year, abc$month),
                      paste(abc.full$year, abc.full$month))] <- abc$amount

abc.full %>% 
  mutate(year = factor(year)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = amount, color = year)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = mutate(abc, year = factor(year))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = factor(1:12),
                   labels = factor(1:12))
```

I'm not sure how you want to display data from multiple years so this is one possibility. I also decided to accentuate the non-zero amounts with points.

[image: amount by month and year]

Comment: You’re right. I neglected to mention about the year and that is how I actually caught my mistake. Thank you     I will look into your implementation. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your 'missing data' issue, you could 'pad' your data with zeros given that they are != NA

```
abc <- tibble(month = c(1:12),
              amount = c(100, 0, 0, 20, rep(0, 7), 300))
```

In answer to your x-axis question, your could try:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = abc, aes(x = month, y = amount, group = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = factor(1:12), # assigns months using factor() to make them discrete 
                   labels = factor(1:12), # assigns labels using factor()
                   expand = c(0, 0)) + # removes space at start/end of x-axis
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) # removes space at start/end of y-axis
```

[image: image of result]